# Calculate sum of products prices inside a ListView as String

Tags: java, android, listview, firebase

I'm new in Android Development. And I'm working with this problem for 3 days.

I have an object class which is saved to Firebase with three **Strings** in a ListView.

```
public class VanzatorProduse {

public String produsId;
public String produs;
public String pret;

public VanzatorProduse(){

}

public VanzatorProduse(String produsId, String produs, String pret) {
    this.produsId = produsId;
    this.produs = produs;
    this.pret = pret;

}

public String getProdusId() {
    return produsId;
}

public String getProdus() {
    return produs;
}

public String getPret() {
    return pret;
}
```

But I want to calculate sum of products prices. If this is possible with Strings, I tried lots of way but no solution.

Here is code where the object is retrieved from Firebase:

```
 databaseReference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            produseVanzatorList.clear();
            for (DataSnapshot produsSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                VanzatorProduse vanzatorProduse = produsSnapshot.getValue(VanzatorProduse.class);

                produseVanzatorList.add(vanzatorProduse);
            }

            VanzatorProduseList adapter = new VanzatorProduseList(ListaProduseActivity.this, produseVanzatorList);
            listViewProduse.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
```

My adapter:

public class VanzatorProduseList extends ArrayAdapter {

```
private Activity context;
private SparseBooleanArray selectedListItemsIds;
private List<VanzatorProduse> vanzatorProduseList;

public VanzatorProduseList(Activity context, List<VanzatorProduse> vanzatorProduseList){
    super(context, R.layout.list_produse_vanzator, vanzatorProduseList);
    this.context = context;
    selectedListItemsIds = new SparseBooleanArray();
    this.vanzatorProduseList = vanzatorProduseList;
}

@NonNull
@Override
public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater  = context.getLayoutInflater();

    View listViewItem = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_produse_vanzator, null, true);

    TextView textViewProdus1 = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewProdus1);
    TextView textViewPret1 = (TextView) listViewItem.findViewById(R.id.textViewPret1);


    VanzatorProduse vanzatorProduse = vanzatorProduseList.get(position);

    textViewProdus1.setText(vanzatorProduse.getProdus());
    textViewPret1.setText(vanzatorProduse.getPret());

    return listViewItem;
}
public SparseBooleanArray getSelectedIds() {
    return selectedListItemsIds;
}
```

Comment: int price = Integer.ParseInt(String value); convert string to int

Comment: can you please show me the code of your adapter?  VanzatorProduseList.java file ?

Comment: whats price in these three pordus,pordusId,pret ? Is pret a price ?

Comment: yes, pret is price

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assumed pret as price.

```
int totalPrice = 0;
for(VanzatorProduse v : produseVanzatorList)
        {
            int vPrice = Integer.parseInt(v.getPret());
            totalPrice = totalPrice + vPrice;
        }
```

Comment: sorry for this silly question, where should i put this code?

Comment: This is completely wrong. There is no `Int` in Java. There is an `int` or an `Integer` object.

Comment: Its ok buddy no issues... you can put it where your list is completed ? after the completion of first for loop  .... After that .... for (DataSnapshot produsSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){

                VanzatorProduse vanzatorProduse = produsSnapshot.getValue(VanzatorProduse.class);

                produseVanzatorList.add(vanzatorProduse);
            }

Comment: It will give me reputation buddy :)

Comment: Sorry spelling mistake buddy @AlexMamo

Comment: @PeterHaddad Hahaha I did it bro ... It was my mistake :p

Comment: @PeterHaddad  Thank you btw :)

Comment: @AlexMamo I am grateful to you. Thank you for correcting me mate :)

Comment: @M.SaadLakhan upvoting you since OP forgot to check it

Comment: @PeterHaddad Bro whats OP?

Comment: @PeterHaddad Thanks alot for your upvode mate :)

Comment: @M.SaadLakhan Original poster, the person posting the question

Answer (score 1):

First of all, there is not a good practice to store int values as Strings in a Firebase database. If you do so, you need to parse the value of the String to an int. Here is an example of how to do it:

```
String string = "10";
int valueOfString =  Integer.valueOf(string);
System.out.println(valueOfString);
```

The output will be: `10`.

There is another important idea when it comes to Firebase, you need to use and declare the `vanzatorProduseList` List inside `onDataChange()` method, otherwise it will be always `null`. Doing this, tehn just iterate trough the List and that's it.

Comment: upvoting you Alex for the important idea +1